# My program is working well except for one thing :

Tags: python

expected input: `"HAHAHAHA"` output is: `"hahaha"`, but it is not printed in one line.

```
def l_case(l):
     for c in l:
          print(chr(ord(c)+32))
```

Comment: Do you need to convert uppercase to lower? If yes you could use `l.lower()`

Comment: What is the input to your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *must* use this method, try this:

```
def l_case(l):
     s = ""
     for c in l:
          s += chr(ord(c)+32)
     print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are defining a function that will convert strings to lower case.  There is already a method that does that:

```
lowercased_string = old_string.lower()
print(lowercased_string)
```

I'm not sure why you are adding `32` to your ordinal, but if I am mistaken about the purpose of your function, the following is how to make each character lowercase and print the characters on the same line:

```
def l_case(l):
    for c in l:
        print(chr(ord(c)+32).lower(), end="")
```

`any_string.lower()` converts `any_string` to lowercase, and `end=""` prevents the new line from being printed.

It would be simpler to do it all with a list comprehension:

```
def l_case(l):
    print("".join(chr(ord(c) + 32).lower() for c in l))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the string method `lower`.  For example:

```
>>> "HAHAHAHA".lower()
'hahahaha'
>>>
```

Note that this will leave things like numbers, punctuation, and letters that are already lowercase unchanged.

Comment: I avoid using buil.in functions bro but thanks for the effort

Comment: If you avoid built in functions you can't use `chr` and `ord`.